# Creating data subsets in R based on a list of variables to exclude

Tags: r, csv, subset

I am trying to analyse subsets of a genepop file in the R package adegenet, and would like to apply different analyses to different subsets of populations (rows) and loci (columns). The subsets are defined by various exclusion criteria, and I have lists of loci and populations to be excluded under different circumstances.

Grabbing subsets of loci and populations in adegenet follows the standard conventions using square brackets, to the question is really quite general. By importing and transposing a list of loci and populations (simple csv files) and including them as objects in the spaces for grab parameters, I have been able create an object which includes only the variables included on those lists. 
i.e.

```
#Selecting top 5 loci based on csv, transpose, then display the names
topfivelocs <- read.csv("top5loci.csv")
top5locs <- t(topfivelocs)

#Selecting to 5 pops based on csv, transpose, then display the names
topfivepops <- read.csv("top5pops.csv")
top5pops <- t(topfivepops)

#Grabbing a subset to top 5 loci for top 5 pops, display pop and loci names, and summarise the subset
fiveXfive <- full.dat[pop=top5pops,loc=c(top5locs)]
```

This successfully creates a genind (dataframe) object containing only the variables on the lists of desired populations and loci. My question is; how to I achieve the negative of this. In otherwords, create a dataframe/genind object including all EXCEPT the listed variables in my csv file.

EDIT
To ask a more simple question, I have a full list of locations in a csv with one column i.e.
Bristol
Edinburgh
London
Cardiff
Bangor
Liverpool

and then a subset of locations to exclude from analysis in the same format i.e. 
Bristol
London
Cardiff

How do I program R to create an object comprising my master list but to the exclusion of those listed in the subset list. That seems a very simple instruction, so there must be a way.

Comment: I am trying to use the logical NOT operator ! to achieve this, but to no effect.
i.e. fiveXfive <- full.dat[!pop=top5pops,!loc=c(top5locs)]

Comment: `pop=top5pops` does not return a logical vector: it assigns the object `top5pops` to the name `pop`. You probably want something like: `full.dat[!pop %in% top5pops, !loc %in% top5locs]`, but it's hard to say without a reproducible example

Comment: I am getting the following error when using the suggested code, and am not sure what it means or how to edit it.

"error in evaluating the argument 'i' in selecting a method for function '[': Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  'match' requires vector arguments"

I would be happy to give you a workable example but I am not sure how I can.

Comment: If you give the output of `dput(head(full.dat))`, `dput(head(top5pops))`, and `dput(head(top5locs))`, it'll be easier to help

Comment: The output for full.dat is more characters than I am allowed, but it looks something like this `new("genind"
    , tab = structure(c(2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, ...  0L, 0L), .Dim = c(1L, 2388L), .Dimnames = list(
    "1", c("cgpGmo-S1001.01", "cgpGmo-S1001.03", "cgpGmo-S1001.00", 
    "cgpGmo-S1006.03", "cgpGmo-S1006.01", "cgpGmo-S1006.00",..."cgpGmo-S9b"))
    , ploidy = 2L
    , type = "codom"
    , other = list()
    , call = .local(x = x, i = i, j = j, drop = drop)
    , pop = structure(1L, .Label = "4T", class = "factor")
    , strata = NULL
    , hierarchy = NULL`

Comment: Output for top5pops `> dput(head(top5pops))
structure(list(Population = structure(1:5, .Label = c("4T", "ARC", 
"Baltic", "Cox", "Flem"), class = "factor")), .Names = "Population", row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")`
and top5locs `> dput(head(top5locs))
structure(list(Locus.name = structure(1:5, .Label = c("cgpGmo-S1001", 
"cgpGmo-S1006", "cgpGmo-S1007", "cgpGmo-S1008", "cgpGmo-S1009"
), class = "factor")), .Names = "Locus.name", row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: You should really add those to your question, not in the comments